# Using ffmpeg to convert an SEC file

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to convert an SEC file into any video format that I can share and/or upload to Youtube. MP4, etc.

I'm a complete newbie at all things terminal. I've tried:

ffmpeg -i video.sec video.mp4

ffmpeg -i video.sec -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:v copy video.avi

ffmpeg -i video.sec -b 256k -vcodec h264 -acodec aac video.mp4

I don't understand what any of these mean, they're just examples I found online. However, whatever I try returns this error:

Invalid data found when processing input

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: sec? what format is that?

Comment: It's some Samsung proprietary format, this file is from a security camera.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following option so it would skip the SEC's custom header.

-skip_initial_bytes 48

Answer (score 1):

i know this is old, but i was trying to figure this out as well, what ended up finally working for me was this command.

```
./ffmpeg -f h264 -i INPUT.sec -filter:v "setpts=4*PTS" OUTPUT.avi
```

the **-f h264** was the part i was missing.  and the **-filter:v "setpts=4*PTS"** part is to slow it back down to the original speed.  you can also change the **.avi** at the end to whichever format works best for you.

i hope this helps someone out :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, just to clear up some recent threads…

The Samsung DVR used here was an SRD-440. RB kindly sent me a file to test and he sent me a .BU file with an associated .db2 file. This was a bit of a surprise as in all older Samsung DVR’s, the .bu files can only be played back in the DVR. I mentioned this here, https://spreadys.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/ifsec-samsung-exports/

It appears that Samsung have caught on, and the BU file is now playable due to it being a H264/AVC Stream conforming to a standard profile. I have updated the IFSEC Post mentioned above to highlight this change.

Back to RB’s stream and the challenge was to get these files viewable in WMV format. They were all field based, at 704×288.

The speed of playback is controlled by the Samsung software, using the .db2 file. As such, the metadata and timing information in the video stream was wrong. This caused speed issues and then quality issues when attempting to correct this.

As a result, I found it necessary to force an input rate and generate a new Presentation Time Stamp BEFORE the input file.

The following FFmpeg string did the job…

```
ffmpeg -r 12 -fflags genpts -i FILE.bu -vf scale=704:528 -sws_flags lanczos -q:v 2 FILE.wmv
```

Remember, this is for preview – analysis would be completed differently due to the scaling, the interpolation method, and the WMV compression!

As its likely that RB may have quite a few .bu files in a folder, I placed this into a batch file to transcode the whole lot within a few minutes… more on batch files coming in a new post soon!

https://spreadys.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/ifsec-samsung-exports/

or

```
ffmpeg -i (name of file).sec (name of final file).mp4

ffmpeg -i (name of file).sec -filter:v "setpts=3.3*PTS"  (name of final_file).mp4
```